# My SQL: find maximum score which id also in the previous date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a question on SQL but I couldn't get the correct result.
The question is in below:
Please use MySQL(5.6 or later) or MariaDB(10.2 or later)

There is a contest start from Jan 01, 2018 and end on Feb 01, 2018.

Write a query to find the member_id and name of the member who makes the highest score each day, the qualifying condition will be that the member must have made at least 1 submission each day, every day starting from 2018-01-01 up to the day (Eg. for 2018-01-03, only members who have made at least 1 submission on both 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-02 are qualified). If more than one such member has the same score, print the one who has the lowest member_id. The result should be this information for each day of the contest, sorted by the date.

Sample Data:

members:

[image]

submissions:

[image]

Sample Result:

[image]

Here is my SQL:
[image]

Please help to provide the solution. Many Thanks.

Comment: No pictures, thanks.

Comment: sorry but it keeps prompting me to use ctrl+K which I don't know where did I do wrong

Comment: Please don't tag SQL Server when your question has nothing to do with. I also suggest reading up on `JOIN` syntax. It's been around since 1992, you should really be using it. Finally, I'd really think about better names for your aliases than `a` and `b`, especially as they represent different things depending on the part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select s.submission_date,m.id,n.name,s.score  
from (select s.submission_date,m.id,n.name,s.score,
rank() over (partition by(s.submission_date) order by s.score desc) rank
from members m,submissions s where m.id=s.member_id) where rank=1;
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't think `partition by` was in MYSQL, my bad then. My point of joins remains however.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take the member_id, submission_date eligible for each day,

Second, take the member_id, name, score, submission_date of above selected member_id

third, filter for max(score) group by submission_date and order by member_id

Comment: Thanks but how to proceed the first step?

Comment: try taking count(member_id) = submission_date - ('2018-01-01') for each day

Comment: sounds nice.,but what if on 2nd day the member never submit but on 3rd day he submit twice?then the count still=3